# Do I have to put separate attention toward my arms?

Tags: biceps, triceps, arms

So as far as I know usually when you work your chest you also work your triceps and when you work your back you usually also work your biceps. By these standards, is it a problem not to have individual days focused specifically toward biceps and triceps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never have specific arm days namely because of what you said; they get engaged heavily on back/chest days respectively.

If you want to get some more arm action going on, you could instead add a bicep segment to the end of your back day, and a tricep segment to the end of your chest day. That way, they're already warmed up, and probably even tired. But that's good! Because when they're already tired, you get more out of each repetition you do.

As an example, I always do a couple of bicep curl variations on the end of my back day. I.e. after pullups and a bunch of row variations. Equally, I do some tricep isolation movements at the end of every chest day.

Having a designated arm day isn't something I would put into a routine. But I wouldn't be opposed to doing it every once in a while, in case I really don't feel like going with the plan for the day.

Comment: I'd agree with this, and just add that if you're on a program with a lot of volume, adding isolation stuff (which is basically what "arms" is) means you've got a first class ticket to tendinitis.

Comment: @EricKaufman - Excellent point. Come to think of it, I might start following that advice more myself. I'm actually in the habit of doing arm isolation work after volume-centric workouts.

Comment: Thanks Alec and EricKaufman, I am now adding 3 sets of 5 bicep curls after I work my back and 3 sets of 5 tricep dumbbell press after I work my chest/shoulders.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your current split, if you're just beginning to workout its better to stick with the compound exercises (squat, bench and deadlift) 3-4 times a week. You can do an isolation day for arms as long as its at least 2 days after doing a chest/back day to give your arm ample time to recover. While you do activate these muscle during some exercises, its generally not to failure. Targeting specific muscles until failure will allow maximum growth.

An example for a split would be

Chest / Tri,
Back / Bi,
Legs / Abs,
Shoulders,
Bi / Tri